# Swift 2.1 - How do I change the uidatepicker so it only allows for time instead of date?

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uidatepicker

The following code below allows for the user to select a date, however I want to change that to 'Time' via AM/PM, so the user can only select a set time instead it being a date. I want this separate and not combined, I appreciate if someone could help me here thanks.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class DatePickerDialog: UIView {

    typealias DatePickerCallback = (date: NSDate) -> Void

    /* Consts */
    private let kDatePickerDialogDefaultButtonHeight:       CGFloat = 50
    private let kDatePickerDialogDefaultButtonSpacerHeight: CGFloat = 1
    private let kDatePickerDialogCornerRadius:              CGFloat = 7
    private let kDatePickerDialogDoneButtonTag:             Int     = 1

    /* Views */
    private var dialogView:   UIView!
    private var titleLabel:   UILabel!
    private var datePicker:   UIDatePicker!
    private var cancelButton: UIButton!
    private var doneButton:   UIButton!

    /* Vars */
    private var defaultDate:    NSDate?
    private var datePickerMode: UIDatePickerMode?
    private var callback:       DatePickerCallback?


    /* Overrides */
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height))

        setupView()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    func setupView() {
        self.dialogView = createContainerView()

        self.dialogView!.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.dialogView!.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

        self.dialogView!.layer.opacity = 0.5
        self.dialogView!.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.3, 1.3, 1)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)

        self.addSubview(self.dialogView!)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first!.addSubview(self)
    }

    /* Handle device orientation changes */
    func deviceOrientationDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        /* TODO */
    }

    /* Create the dialog view, and animate opening the dialog */
    func show(title: String, datePickerMode: UIDatePickerMode = .Date, callback: DatePickerCallback) {
        show(title, doneButtonTitle: "Done", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", datePickerMode: datePickerMode, callback: callback)
    }

    func show(title: String, doneButtonTitle: String, cancelButtonTitle: String, defaultDate: NSDate = NSDate(), datePickerMode: UIDatePickerMode = .Date, callback: DatePickerCallback) {
        self.titleLabel.text = title
        self.doneButton.setTitle(doneButtonTitle, forState: .Normal)
        self.cancelButton.setTitle(cancelButtonTitle, forState: .Normal)
        self.datePickerMode = datePickerMode
        self.callback = callback
        self.defaultDate = defaultDate
        self.datePicker.datePickerMode = self.datePickerMode ?? .Date
        self.datePicker.date = self.defaultDate ?? NSDate()

        /* Anim */
        UIView.animateWithDuration(
            0.2,
            delay: 0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
            animations: { () -> Void in
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4)
                self.dialogView!.layer.opacity = 1
                self.dialogView!.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)
            },
            completion: nil
        )
    }

    /* Dialog close animation then cleaning and removing the view from the parent */
    private func close() {
        let currentTransform = self.dialogView.layer.transform

        let startRotation = (self.valueForKeyPath("layer.transform.rotation.z") as? NSNumber) as? Double ?? 0.0
        let rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation((CGFloat)(-startRotation + M_PI * 270 / 180), 0, 0, 0)

        self.dialogView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(rotation, CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1))
        self.dialogView.layer.opacity = 1

        UIView.animateWithDuration(
            0.2,
            delay: 0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone,
            animations: { () -> Void in
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
                self.dialogView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(currentTransform, CATransform3DMakeScale(0.6, 0.6, 1))
                self.dialogView.layer.opacity = 0
            }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                for v in self.subviews {
                    v.removeFromSuperview()
                }

                self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    /* Creates the container view here: create the dialog, then add the custom content and buttons */
    private func createContainerView() -> UIView {
        let screenSize = countScreenSize()
        let dialogSize = CGSizeMake(
            300,
            230
                + kDatePickerDialogDefaultButtonHeight
                + kDatePickerDialogDefaultButtonSpacerHeight)

        // For the black background
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)

        // This is the dialog's container; we attach the custom content and the buttons to this one
        let dialogContainer = UIView(frame: CGRectMake((screenSize.width - dialogSize.width) / 2, (screenSize.height - dialogSize.height) / 2, dialogSize.width, dialogSize.height))

        // First, we style the dialog to match the iOS8 UIAlertView >>>
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer(layer: self.layer)
        gradient.frame = dialogContainer.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor(red: 218/255, green: 218/255, blue: 218/255, alpha: 1).CGColor,
            UIColor(red: 233/255, green: 233/255, blue: 233/255, alpha: 1).CGColor,
            UIColor(red: 218/255, green: 218/255, blue: 218/255, alpha: 1).CGColor]

        let cornerRadius = kDatePickerDialogCornerRadius
        gradient.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        dialogContainer.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)

        dialogContainer.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        dialogContainer.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 198/255, green: 198/255, blue: 198/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
        dialogContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1
        dialogContainer.layer.shadowRadius = cornerRadius + 5
        dialogContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
        dialogContainer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0 - (cornerRadius + 5) / 2, 0 - (cornerRadius + 5) / 2)
        dialogContainer.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        dialogContainer.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: dialogContainer.bounds, cornerRadius: dialogContainer.layer.cornerRadius).CGPath

        // There is a line above the button
        let lineView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, dialogContainer.bounds.size.height - kDatePickerDialogDefaultButtonHeight - kDatePickerDialogDefaultButtonSpacerHeight, dialogContainer.bounds.size.width, kDatePickerDialogDefaultButtonSpacerHeight))
        lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 198/255, green: 198/255, blue: 198/255, alpha: 1)
        dialogContainer.addSubview(lineView)
        // ˆˆˆ

        //Title
        self.titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 280, 30))
        self.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        self.titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)
        dialogContainer.addSubview(self.titleLabel)

        self.datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRectMake(0, 30, 0, 0))
        self.datePicker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin
        self.datePicker.frame.size.width = 300
        dialogContainer.addSubview(self.datePicker)

        // Add the buttons
        addButtonsToView(dialogContainer)

        return dialogContainer
    }

    /* Add buttons to container */
    private func addButtonsToView(container: UIView) {
        let buttonWidth = container.bounds.size.width / 2

        self.cancelButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        self.cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(
            0,
            container.bounds.size.height - kDatePickerDialogDefaultButtonHeight,
            buttonWidth,
            kDatePickerDialogDefaultButtonHeight
        )
        self.cancelButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.5, blue: 1, alpha: 1), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.cancelButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 0.5), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
        self.cancelButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)
        self.cancelButton.layer.cornerRadius = kDatePickerDialogCornerRadius
        container.addSubview(self.cancelButton)

        self.doneButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        self.doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(
            buttonWidth,
            container.bounds.size.height - kDatePickerDialogDefaultButtonHeight,
            buttonWidth,
            kDatePickerDialogDefaultButtonHeight
        )
        self.doneButton.tag = kDatePickerDialogDoneButtonTag
        self.doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.5, blue: 1, alpha: 1), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 0.5), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
        self.doneButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)
        self.doneButton.layer.cornerRadius = kDatePickerDialogCornerRadius
        self.doneButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        container.addSubview(self.doneButton)
    }

    func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
        if sender.tag == kDatePickerDialogDoneButtonTag {
            self.callback?(date: self.datePicker.date)
        }

        close()
    }

    /* Helper function: count and return the screen's size */
    func countScreenSize() -> CGSize {
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        return CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenHeight)
    }

}
```

Here is the action in a separate view controller.

```
@IBAction func datePickerTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        DatePickerDialog().show("Select Date of Incident", doneButtonTitle: "Done", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", datePickerMode: .Date) {
            (date) -> Void in
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" //format style. you can change according to yours
            let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
            self.textField3.text = dateString
        } 
    }
```

Comment: `datePicker.datePickerMode = .Time`

Comment: @Leo Dabus Its not working, I used that and I am getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "separately," you mean prompting for the date and then prompting for the time, you can simply call the show method again and pass in the appropriate UIDatePickerMode (.Time in this case) and format your time according to your requirements.

Like so:

```
DatePickerDialog().show("Select Time of Incident", doneButtonTitle: "Done", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", datePickerMode: .Time) {
    //format your time accordingly
    //self.textField3.text = timeString
}
```

Comment: I have got it working partially, the time shows however the date also appears as well, how do I disable the date?

Comment: Where do you see the date? In the dialog after the time? If you don't want the date at all, don't call the DatePickerDialog().show method where you ask for the Date (in your code sample from the question).

Comment: I see the date when its populated in the textfield, when i get rid of the DatePickerDialog().show I get a lot of errors.

Comment: You need to implement the correct time formatting instead of using the date formatting from your example. I uploaded a sample app: https://github.com/madethelflint/DatePickerDialogExample

Comment: Thank you for your help and time, your a star! I have marked this question as answered now.